# UIWindow overlay not visible

Tags: ios, uiwindow

Tring to add an overlay window to the key UIWindow in the IOS app.
However, it seems that the new overlay UIWindow is not anywhere visible.

It seems that it is being added successfully though, based on lldb:

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <UIWindow: 0x7fdfd3d0aec0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800004d680>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x608000220980>>
  - 1 : <UIWindow: 0x7fdfd3c0d010; frame = (0 0; 375 667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000004c9c0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000002216e0>>
```

In the debug,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let window = UIWindow()
    window.frame = self.view.bounds
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
    window.rootViewController = vc
    window.isHidden = false
}
```

Would appreciate any sort of hint/help
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window is being deallocated after your `viewDidLoad()` method exits. You need to strongly retain your second window.

Comment: Thanks Leo, explicitly retaining the window fixed the issue. Wish I could find this requirement in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, Apple's documentation of window-related topics is lacking. Make sure to open an enhancement request for the documentation at https://bugreport.apple.com